# Avoid duplicate SQL code in Spring data class

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Spring data has its own annotation 'Query', that associates SQL query with Java. It often uses one query per a method in repository.

My question: has spring data the way to write query once and use it multiply times?

For example, replace this code

```
@Repository
public interface StuffRepository extends JpaRepository<Stuff, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Stuff> {


    @Query(value = "SELECT s "
        + "FROM Stuff s "
        + "JOIN s.foo f"
        + "WHERE f.id = :id")
    Page<Stuff> findByFooId(@Param("id") String id,  Pageable pageable);

    @Query(value = "SELECT s "
        + "FROM Stuff s "
        + "JOIN s.foo f"
        + "WHERE f.id = :id")
    List<Stuff> findByFooId(@Param("id") String id);

    @Query(value = "SELECT s "
        + "FROM Stuff s "
        + "JOIN s.foo f"
        + "WHERE f.id = :id")
    Stuff findByFooIdFirst(@Param("id") String id);
}
```

to something like this

```
@Repository
public interface StuffRepository extends JpaRepository<Stuff, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Stuff> {


    @Query(value = "SELECT s "     //create query findByFooId
        + "FROM Stuff s "
        + "JOIN s.foo f"
        + "WHERE f.id = :id",
        name = "findByFooId"
    )
    Page<Stuff> findByFooId(@Param("id") String id,  Pageable pageable);

    @Query(name = "findByFooId")   // link to query
    List<Stuff> findByFooId(@Param("id") String id);



    @Query(name = "findByFooId")   //link to query
    Stuff findByFooIdFirst(@Param("id") String id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use static string for query like

```
@Repository
public interface StuffRepository extends JpaRepository<Stuff, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Stuff> {


String QUERY = "SELECT s "    
    + "FROM Stuff s "
    + "JOIN s.foo f"
    + "WHERE f.id = :id";

@Query(value = QUERY)   
List<Stuff> findByFooId(@Param("id") String id);


@Query(value= QUERY)   
Page<Stuff> findByFooId(@Param("id") String id,  Pageable pageable);
```